# Looping over an array of URL end points

Tags: php

Hey guys thanks in advance to all,
So Iv made a `conditional` statement for a plugin that runs on woocommerce, to target the `URL` so I can inject custom css via php or whatever.
the code works fine, but I trying to make it cleaner using an `array` instead of rewriting the statment every time

this is the code hope you guys could help cheers,

```
//add css if uri contains product base number

add_action('init', 'do_stuff');
function do_stuff()
{
 $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 if (false !== strpos($url, 'product_base=22')) {
  echo '<style type="text/css"></style>';
 }
}
```

this is the array I was thinking about looping over there are two options one with the full path and the other a constant path of `product_base` with a dynamic number from the array

```
$product_base = array('product_base=21','product_base=22','product_base=23');

$product_key = array('21','22','23');
```

cheers again,

Comment: This seems to be a very bad idea. I think you can hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` and use one of the Woocommerce function to get the product id and enqueue your style. Checking each URL on init and then adding css is not the way to go.

Comment: Hey thanks wrote it down, anyways its just a random example the main thing is targeting the specific product via the url path and run a custom code , but in this case the plugin I'm using is kind of creating its own url's there are no standard woo commerce `end points` so I cant use any of the woo commerce built in functions (I'v tried). this is currently my workaround of targeting specific products within the website

Comment: What plugin it is? Maybe I can give it a spin on my local setup and help you out with a proper workaround. 

And if the plugin is just appending product ids in URL, you can probably use $_GET['product_base'] to match the product id and perform a specific operation. Can you add a sample URL in here

Comment: Hey not currently its only on local right now, Im using a premium plugin called `lumise product designer` it allows you to mock up products.
Il try as soon as possible to create a link. cheers

Comment: I just wanted to see the URL structure don't really need to access it. So local URL should be ok as well

Comment: Oh sorry bro, the URL looks like this, `http://www.domain.com/design-editor/?product_base=30&product_cms=542` notice that although Iv assigned a product category via woo commerce its not appearing in the path cheers,
you can check a live demo in [here](https://demo.lumise.com/?select-demo=frontend)